# PHP variable between 2 string positions

Tags: php, string, variables, position, extract

I have tried searching the forums but still unsure how to do this.

I am extracting a web link from a webpage, and the start and end are always the same but there is a variable i want to get.

E.g http://www.example.com/images/$VARIABLE/image.jpg

$position1 = http://www.example.com/images/

$position2 = image.jpg

I need to get the variable. On the webpage the $position 2 is listed more than once (image.jpg)

I have tried all sorts of things and nothing works so far.

Thank you

```
$begin = strpos($page, $position1) + strlen($position1); 
$end   = strpos($page, $position2);
$ImageName = substr($page, $begin, ($end - $begin));
```

Comment: Other than needing `$end - $begin - 1`, what is wrong with your existing code?

Comment: Is there a pattern? Maybe `http://www.example.com/images/([^/]+)/image.jpg` with `preg_match` then take capture group 1.

Comment: Have you used pase_url()?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I have tried the suggestions yet still not working. How can i set the position, then add 64 characters beyond the position to make it one big string?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that if image.jpg occurs before http://www.example.com/images/, then just trying to use your code won't work.

A slight fix would be to start the search for `$position2` where you found the first part by adding a start point in the `strpos()` function...

```
$begin = strpos($page, $position1) + strlen($position1);
$end   = strpos($page, $position2, $begin);
$ImageName = substr($page, $begin, ($end - $begin) - 1);
```

with

```
$page = "some test image.jpg some more text  
blurb that is in the middle http://www.example.com/images/VARIABLE/image.jpg 
some even more text image.jpg";
```

the code finds

```
VARIABLE
```

A regex as suggested by @user3783243 may also work, but you may also need a constraint of how long the parameter is likely to be.

Comment: thank you, it still is not working for some reason. Is there a way to find the position, then add 64 characters beyond the position?

Comment: Can you show an example of the text so that I can test it.